What is rigid disk block (RDB) and how can I repair it?
I have a WD P10 external USB disk that is no longer being detected on macOS or Windows (on a different PC). To troubleshoot, I booted Debian (LMDE) from a Live USB and connected the WD drive again. It wasn't detected or mounted by it. This is what dmesg -wH says:
[ 1305.848487] usb 4-4: new SuperSpeed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
[ 1305.869379] usb 4-4: New USB device found, idVendor=1058, idProduct=262f, bcdDevice=50.02
[ 1305.869393] usb 4-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
[ 1305.869397] usb 4-4: Product: Game Drive
[ 1305.869400] usb 4-4: Manufacturer: Western Digital
[ 1305.869403] usb 4-4: SerialNumber: 00000000000000
[ 1305.872247] usb-storage 4-4:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 1305.875321] scsi host7: usb-storage 4-4:1.0
[ 1306.881494] scsi 7:0:0:0: Direct-Access     WD       Game Drive       5002 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[ 1306.881988] sd 7:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[ 1306.883093] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] Spinning up disk...
[ 1307.904413] .........ready
[ 1316.097814] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] Very big device. Trying to use READ CAPACITY(16).
[ 1316.098549] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] 7813969920 512-byte logical blocks: (4.00 TB/3.64 TiB)
[ 1316.098558] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] 4096-byte physical blocks
[ 1316.099943] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
[ 1316.099949] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 47 00 10 08
[ 1316.101378] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] No Caching mode page found
[ 1316.101384] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 1352.000492] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[ 1357.376496] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[ 1357.584400] usb 4-4: device not accepting address 8, error -62
[ 1363.008491] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[ 1368.384501] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[ 1368.592421] usb 4-4: device not accepting address 8, error -62
[ 1374.016518] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[ 1379.392520] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[ 1379.600423] usb 4-4: device not accepting address 8, error -62
[ 1385.024482] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[ 1390.400527] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[ 1390.608418] usb 4-4: device not accepting address 8, error -62
[ 1390.624755] usb 4-4: USB disconnect, device number 8
[ 1390.644397] blk_print_req_error: 2 callbacks suppressed
[ 1390.644406] device offline error, dev sdc, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 2
[ 1390.644422] buffer_io_error: 2 callbacks suppressed
[ 1390.644424] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc, logical block 0, async page read
[ 1390.644527] device offline error, dev sdc, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 2
[ 1390.644542] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc, logical block 0, async page read
[ 1390.644580] device offline error, dev sdc, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 2
[ 1390.644587] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc, logical block 0, async page read
[ 1390.644610] device offline error, dev sdc, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 2
[ 1390.644616] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc, logical block 0, async page read
[ 1390.644629] ldm_validate_partition_table(): Disk read failed.
[ 1390.644660] device offline error, dev sdc, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 2
[ 1390.644663] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc, logical block 0, async page read
[ 1390.644675] device offline error, dev sdc, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 2
[ 1390.644678] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc, logical block 0, async page read
[ 1390.644691] device offline error, dev sdc, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 2
[ 1390.644694] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc, logical block 0, async page read
[ 1390.644706] device offline error, dev sdc, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 2
[ 1390.644709] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc, logical block 0, async page read
[ 1390.644714] Dev sdc: unable to read RDB block 0
[ 1390.644724] device offline error, dev sdc, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 2
[ 1390.644727] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc, logical block 0, async page read
[ 1390.644739] device offline error, dev sdc, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 2
[ 1390.644742] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc, logical block 0, async page read
[ 1390.644784]  sdc: unable to read partition table
[ 1390.644844] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI disk
[ 1396.032462] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[ 1401.408460] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[ 1401.616427] usb 4-4: device not accepting address 9, error -62
[ 1407.040457] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[ 1412.416466] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[ 1412.624428] usb 4-4: device not accepting address 10, error -62
[ 1412.632542] usb usb4-port4: attempt power cycle
[ 1418.816454] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[ 1424.192454] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[ 1424.400426] usb 4-4: device not accepting address 11, error -62
[ 1429.824465] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[ 1435.200470] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[ 1435.408388] usb 4-4: device not accepting address 12, error -62
[ 1435.416544] usb usb4-port4: unable to enumerate USB device

(Serial number of drive has been edited by me).
From what I could understand, it tries to get the partition information from the drive, but fails. So it still tries to "attach" the disk (probably to allow user to format the drive) but again fails for reasons I cannot understand.
When I search online for Dev sdc: unable to read RDB block 0 this resource from Red Hat says:

The Dev sdx: unable to read RDB block 0 message indicates the system is not able to pull the Rigid Disk Block (RDB) information from the disk. The RDB stores disk's geometry (cylinders, heads, sectors) and partitioning information.

But Wikipedia says:

In computing, a rigid disk block (RDB) is the block on a hard disk where the Amiga series of computers store the disk's partition and filesystem information. The IBM's PC equivalent of the Amiga's RDB is the master boot record (MBR).

From what Red Hat says, it sounds very much like the RDB is part of the HDD firmware, which means it may very difficult to repair for a lay person without specialised software. But if it is part of the MBR or filesystem, we could use some tools to repair it (if I am somehow able to tell the OS how to attach the disk successfully).
Hence my doubt - What is rigid disk block (RDB), in Linux, and can it be repaired? For example, Amiga has rdbtool - is something equivalent available in Linux?

After the [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through message, the kernel is trying to detect the partitioning scheme used on the disk, and read the partition table. But the USB layer is reporting the device is timing out as soon as the kernel is trying to set it up for use, in order to read disk block #0. The repeated timeouts in setting up the disk (device is not accepting address...) are causing the USB layer to reject the device, treating it as a USB disconnect.
Apparently the kernel code responsible for partition detection does not care about the reason why its read attempt failed: if the detection routine for a particular partitioning scheme reports a failure, the kernel will attempt to detect any other partitioning scheme it knows about, and only gives up after it's tried them all.
The message ldm_validate_partition_table(): Disk read failed indicates kernel is at that point trying to detect Windows LDM partitions (Dynamic Disks in Windows terminology). That is also failing because an attempt to read the disk fails.
The message Dev sdc: unable to read RDB block 0 indicates the kernel has now tried to detect all partitioning schemes native to your system architecture (for PCs, those would be MBR, GPT, the above-mentioned LDM, and Solaris/Unixware disk slices), and is now proceeding to more esoteric ones: specifically, here it's looking for an Amiga-style partition table and failing, again because an attempt to read disk block #0 fails.
In classic PC MBR partitioning scheme, block #0 is called Master Boot Record (or MBR for short); because there is no other well-known name for this partitioning scheme, the entire scheme is called "MBR partitioning".
In Amiga-style partitioning, disk block #0 is called the Rigid Disk Block, or RDB for short. It is not part of the firmware: it is just a Amiga-specific way to describe the disk and its partitions in a way that is independent of AmigaOS version used. It is written when the disk is partitioned by an Amiga disk partitioning tool.
In short, the error messages referring to LDM and RDB are not important in your case: they were just a side effect of the kernel trying and failing to find any type of partition table it knows about. As the Amiga partition detection code is originally written for the Amiga port of Linux, it uses Amiga terminology in its error messages.
Your most immediate problem is that your disk seems to be dead: it does not respond to any attempts to read it, or even to set it up for access. This is a hardware or disk firmware issue of some sort. If the disk keeps failing to set up USB communications, you won't be able to use any regular software to recover data from it.
In the comments, you mentioned this external disk has a direct USB interface: there is no USB-to-SATA converter that could be disconnected to allow a SATA interface to be used. This is going to make data recovery harder.
You would need some disk manufacturing/QA tools that would bypass the USB connection and allow you to communicate directly with the controller chips, which sounds like a job for data recovery professionals to me.

Sigh, this is such a PITA. Forget about repairing faulty disks, it's pretty annoying that none of the S/HDD manufacturers offer to at least diagnose a faulty disk to aid us in data recovery. (Thanks for the great explanation of the dmesg output.)

Since the issue manifests with different PCs, this sounds like a hardware problem which cannot be overcome by software tools alone. Keep in mind that there are multiple components involved:
USB-Controller – USB-Cable – USB-SATA-Bridge – SATA-Connector – Hard-Drive
By using different PCs, you already ruled the USB-Controller. Next trivial step is to try a different USB-Cable.
I had some drives where the USB-SATA-Bridge (I assume SATA) failed. In this situation, you can carefully open the external disk's housing, remove the actual disk and attach it to your PC's internal SATA connectors.
However, it is more likely that the disk itself is failing to start. The USB-SATA-Bridge loses connection to the disk and shuts itself down. This explains the behaviour "USB Mass Storage device detected", "Spinning up disk...", "USB disconnect".

I have tried a different (working) USB cable and the issue persists. I have also opened the protective casing and found there is no SATA connector on the HDD - it only has a USB 3 connector. I also had come across a resource that said that if there is a PCB problem, the HDD won't power up - in my case, the drive does spin up when connected and then spins down after some time.
